# Circuit Breaker Disconnect

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a circuit I no longer want active. All switches, outlets, etc. are disconnected, but wires still remain in the wall. If I disconnect the hot wire from the breaker, do I also need to remove the white wire?

Comment: Probably don't have to, but I would and loop/place both wires plus ground, out of the way, even removed from the panel and label/leave a note of why they are there for the future.  Nothing worst than someone in the future finding a wire with no use/purpose, unless you want to drive them batty.

Comment: Neutral is a live conductor, and can float at voltages well above ground. It's insulated for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

I can't say if it is *required*. But definitely highly recommended. If you leave the white wire connected to the neutral bar, the next person will be trying to figure out either (a) what hot wire came loose and where does it go and what device isn't working as a result or (b) will be trying to reuse the existing wires and wonder why the neutral was still connected.

The best thing is to cap both wires with wire nuts and tag them together so that it is clear they are part of one circuit, and label that with an indicator of where the other end goes.

Ground is a different story. If you are using metal conduit, ground is provided without connecting a separate wire. And if you are not using metal conduit, it isn't a bad idea to leave grounds connected all the time. Unlike neutral, which may be connected differently for a GFCI or AFCI breaker, grounds are always connected the same way. Also unlike neutral, ground only carries current when something goes wrong.